# how to add paypal payment method in web project?

Tags: paypal

How are you.
I am building job site and I would like to handle payment between client and freelancer by paypal.
To do it, I think developer should attach their paypal to his account.
I have searched how to do it, but all the example are to make direct payment button.
There are 2 senarios to pay freelancer.

1. Direct payment from client to freelancer

   when client approve work, he can release directly without admin side.
2. List item

   Client first fund money to admin paypal and when job completed, admin paypal release money to freelancer account.

How can I solve this kinds of problem?
Thanks

Comment: i do not understannd your question. Is option 1 not a direct payment from the client to the freelancer? And option 2 a direct payment from client to admin followed by a direct payment from admin to freelancer?

Comment: Yes, second have 2 steps, actually the principles are same

Comment: But why is each step **not** a direct payment?

Comment: I mean, it's direct payment, those are same :)
If you can help me, l will pay for this.

Comment: Other than asking have you read the [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/#payment_execute) (and I do not mean just the one item, I mean the whole thing), I can not help you because I can not understand your question.